# Create a gmail / googleapp edu e-mail account using API

Tags: google-apps

Is it possible to create a gmail account or googleappedu e-mail account using API? So that everytime we add a new student in our system we don't have to create (or upload) manually on admin.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer from this [googledocs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ixVHcT85nhaU8yYUzi4SEaEMocqkRSSC_Y5GpUtUCVI/edit) (segment 5)

> Provisioning API The Provisioning API allows for users to be created
>   programmatically. If you’re interested in learning more, take a look
>   at the Provisioning API documentation.

There are [admin-sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/?csw=1) (Directory API is new Provisioning API).